# How to make my function to thread over additions?

Tags: function-construction

I have a function `f[x]`. Can I make it to thread over sums automatically?

I mean I want to declare it distributive against addition.

Comment: Please have a look under Scope [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html?q=Listable).

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what hmm, looked. It seems it talks about lists, not sums.

Comment: You're right, my mistake.

Comment: Check out Distribute.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it thus:

```
f[sum_Plus] := f /@ sum;
```

Comment: I don't understand the subtraction thing in the other answers. It's not in the question. For instance, what's `f[x - 2y]` supposed to be?  It's an odd property to have.  Most operators that have such property have it because they are *linear* and not just additive.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, quite simple if I am not mistaken:

`f[x_ + y_] := f[x] + f[y];`

and before the main definition of the function, to handle subtraction:

`f[-x_] := -f[x];`

It seems to work for any number of terms.

Comment: @BobHanlon no, works for any number of arguments here. Does not work with subtraction though.

Answer (score 1):

Using `FullForm` in your definitions:

```
f[Plus[x_, y_]]:= f[x] + f[y]
f[Plus[x_, Times[-1,y_]]]:= f[x] - f[y]
```

Test:

```
f[a + b]
(*f[a] + f[b]*)
f[a - b]
(*f[a] - f[b]*)
```